# Method call won't even compile

Tags: c#

Just learning C# as Unity scripts. The following doesn't compile. I've gotten around the problem by putting the code in "void update"  but I'm obviously missing something. I've put a comment where the compiler failed.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ThrottleControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public float 
        ThrottlePosition,
        ThrottleEffectiveness,
        ThrottleReturnSpeed;

    private string ThrottleStr = "Throttle";

    void GetThrottlePosition()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown (ThrottleStr)) 
        {
            //code here eliminated for clarity
        }
    } // GetThrottle Position


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ThrottleEffectiveness = 0.1f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { //compiler error here about allowed statements
        GetThrottlePosition; 
    }
}
```

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Exact compiler error, please.

Comment: Need () to call a method. `GetThrottlePosition()`

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial Method Calling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm)

Comment: [How does one correctly call a method in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend learning the basics of C# in a more traditional environment (e.g. simple Windows console apps) before moving on to Unity. Otherwise you won't be able to tell which errors are Unity quirks and which are simple C# errors.

Comment: Yup. That's embarrassing. Thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 5):

`GetThrottlePosition` needs to be called with empty parens

```
void Update () 
{
    GetThrottlePosition(); 
}
```